# AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled for Key Information Extraction as Character-wise Classification with LSTM

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

Im trying to implement the train.py file from [this repo](https://github.com/zzzDavid/ICDAR-2019-SROIE/tree/master/task3) but the error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/train.py", line 74, in <module>
    main()
  File "./src/train.py", line 21, in main
    model = MyModel0(len(VOCAB), 20, args.hidden_size).to(args.device)
  File "/home/guest/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 426, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File "/home/guest/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 202, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/guest/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 224, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "/home/guest/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 424, in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() else None, non_blocking)
  File "/home/guest/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 192, in _lazy_init
    _check_driver()
  File "/home/guest/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 95, in _check_driver
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

Even though the # torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = False, I'm still getting this error. Maybe there's more GPU dependencies which I'm not familiar with. I'm not so familiar with PyTorch, any suggestions, please?